# Stop Image from overlapping the screen, causing to have a scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Stop Image from overlapping the screen, causing to have a scroll bar.
the

it should be like this,

https://jsfiddle.net/Luudbo02/1/

```
<section class="sec1">
Hello
</section>
<section class="sec2">
  <div class="sec2-1">
    Image
 </div>
```

```
.sec1{
background: #ccc;
padding:20px;  
z-index: 9999999;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.sec2{
position: relative;
height: 200px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.sec2-1{
transform: scale(1.2);
background: red;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: `body {overflow-x: hidden;}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the attribute `overflow: hidden` to `.sec2`.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `transform: scale(1.2);` in `.sec2-1` class

```
.sec2-1{
 background: red;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
}
```

or add `overflow:hidden` on `.sec2` class.

like this:

```
.sec2{
   overflow:hidden;
   position: relative;
   height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

Comment: I need that to zoom my image, michael figure it out by adding overflow :)